# Troubleshooting adding fonts to react native project

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, react-native

I'm trying to add some custom fonts to my react-native project. I put my font files in `/fonts` folder and added this snippet to `package.json`:

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": ["./fonts"]
}
```

and ran `react-native link`. I'm able to use the fonts on Android. So far so good.

The problem is on iOS. So, I've read all of the stack overflow questions about this problem and none of the solutions worked. I've:

1. **Made sure that they're included in the target**. The checkbox next to my project name in the target membership box is checked.
2. **Double checked that my fonts are included as resources in my bundle**.[image: fonts are included as resources in my bundle]
3. **Included the fonts in the application plist**.[image: plist info] These first 3 steps were done properly by `react-native link`.
4. **Cleaned the project and rebuilt**.
5. **Killed the packager and then reran the project**.

Still I can't use the fonts. So I added this snippet to my `appDelegate.m`:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

which prints all available font names to the xCode log. It seems that I'm only able to use Graphik-Medium:

[image: Graphik-Medium]

Graphik Web appeared elsewhere on the list with a messed up font name:

[image: Graphik-Web]

bebas-neue is nowhere to be found on this list.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible that the fonts are not compatible with iOS?

Comment: I had an issue once where the font in xcode wasn't what the file was named, but what the content of the file declared the font name to be.

Comment: I ended up solving this by using .otf files instead of .ttf

Answer (score 0):

This is how we got our custom fonts to run in both iOS/Android so hope this is helpful to you. Delete `node_modules`, clear simulator history and delete the iOS `build` folder. We manually drop the fonts (BOTH .otf and .ttf) into the `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` and then `ios` folders. Then in XCode we make sure they are in the "Fonts provided by application" section in the `Info.plist`, then make sure they are in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in "Build Phases". If we are updating them, we delete them and reinstall them in that section. Then if you reinstall everything it should work. Hope this helps!!